# How can I find the joint MGF of this density?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

The joint density of the variables $X$ and $Y$ is

$$f(x,y)={{e^{-y}}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-{1\over2}(x-y)^2}; 0<y<\infty,-\infty<x<\infty$$

a)Find the joint moment generating function of $X$ and $Y$. $(M_{XY}(t_1,t_2))$

I think there is a strategy to solve it, maybe completing the density to a normal distribution.

I'm trying to simplify that and after replace the MGF of a normal $N(y,1)$ obtain that
$$M_{XY}(t_1,t_2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^{\infty}(e^{t_1x+t_2y})\left({{e^{-y}}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{1\over2}(x-y)^2}\right)dydx=e^{{t_1^2}\over2}\int_0^\infty e^{y^n}dy$$

But I don't know if it's correct

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your $f(x)$ [should be $f(x,y)$ btw]. The integral giving normalization $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy f(x,y)$ is divergent (while it should be equal to $1$). Could you please double-check and edit?

Comment: Thanks for comment,  it is already edited